# Aligning Child Components Under Corresponding Columns in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native project and facing an issue with aligning child components (ProductTableRow) under their corresponding columns defined in a parent component (ProductTableHeader). Despite using matching flex values for both headers and rows, the child components within each row do not align perfectly under their respective headers.

**Parent Component (SaleScreen):**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import ProductsList from "../components/ProductList";
import CustomersSelect from "../components/CustomersSelect";
import ProductTableHeader from "../components/ProductTableHeader";
import ProductTableRow from "../components/ProductTableRow";

const SaleScreen = () => {
  const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* Product.getPurchased().then((r) => {
      setProducts(r.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });*/
  }, []);

  const calculateTotals = () => {
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;

    selectedProducts.forEach((product) => {
      totalQuantity += product.quantity; // Assuming each product has a 'quantity' property
      totalPrice += product.price * product.quantity; // Assuming each product has a 'price' property
    });

    return { totalQuantity, totalPrice };
  };

  const { totalQuantity, totalPrice } = calculateTotals();

  const onSaveQuantity = (productId, newQuantity) => {
    setSelectedProducts((currentProducts) =>
      currentProducts.map((product) =>
        product.id === productId
          ? { ...product, quantity: parseInt(newQuantity, 10) }
          : product
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.header}></View>
      <View style={styles.divider}>
        <View style={{ width: "50%", height: "100%" }}>
          <ProductsList
            selectedProducts={selectedProducts}
            setSelectedProducts={setSelectedProducts}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            width: "50%",
            borderLeftWidth: 2,
            borderLeftColor: "black",
            height: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <CustomersSelect />
          <View style={{ width: "100%", flex: 1 }}>
            <ProductTableHeader />

            <ScrollView
              style={{ maxHeight: 300, borderColor: "black", borderWidth: 1 }}
              contentContainerStyle={{
                flexGrow: 1,
                alignItems: "stretch",
                borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: 1,
              }}
            >
              {selectedProducts?.map((p) => {
                return (
                  <ProductTableRow
                    product={p}
                    onSaveQuantity={onSaveQuantity}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.totalsRow}>
            <Text>Total Quantity: {totalQuantity}</Text>
            <Text>Total Price: {totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: colors.lightGold,
    height: 80,
  },
  divider: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  headerText: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});
export default SaleScreen;
```

**Child Component 1 (ProductTableHeader):**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";

const ProductTableHeader = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginTop: 20,
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Code</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 40,
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 3,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Product Name</Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>U/P (KWD)</Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Disc (%)</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Qty</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Net Price</Text>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.green,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          borderColor: "black",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Amt (KWD)</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductTableHeader;
```

**Child Component 2 (ProductTableRow):**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Pressable } from "react-native";
    import ProductTableNumber from "./ProductTableNumber";
    import ProductTableProduct from "./ProductTableProduct";
    import ProductSelectionModal from "./ProductSelectionModal";
    
    const ProductTableRow = ({ product, onSaveQuantity }) => {
      const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
      return (
        <Pressable
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            marginBottom: 3,
            alignItems: "center",
            borderColor: "green",
            borderWidth: 2,
        
          }}
          onPress={() => setShowModal(true)}
        >
          <ProductTableNumber value={product.code} />
          <ProductTableProduct en={product.enName} ar={product.arName} />
          <ProductTableNumber value={product.price} />
          <ProductTableNumber value="0.0" />
          <ProductTableNumber value={product.quantity} />
          <ProductTableNumber value={product.price} />
          <ProductTableNumber
            value={(product.price * product.quantity).toFixed(3)}
          />
          <ProductSelectionModal
            showModal={showModal}
            toggleModal={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
            product={product}
            onSaveQuantity={onSaveQuantity}
          />
        </Pressable>
      );
    };
    
    export default ProductTableRow;
ProductTableNumber Component:
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const ProductTableNumber = (props) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flex: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}
    >
      <Text>{props.value}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductTableNumber;
```

**ProductTableProduct Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const ProductTableProduct = (props) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: 40,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
        flex: 3,
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}
    >
      {props.en && <Text>{props.en}</Text>}
      {props.ar && <Text>{props.ar}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductTableProduct;
```

**ProductTableNumber Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const ProductTableNumber = (props) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flex: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}
    >
      <Text>{props.value}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductTableNumber;
```

**Issue Description:**
Each row in my table is a Pressable component containing several child components that represent table data (ProductTableNumber and ProductTableProduct). Despite setting consistent flex values across corresponding columns in the header and rows, the alignment is off.

**Expected Result:**
Each column in ProductTableRow should align directly under its corresponding column in ProductTableHeader.

**Actual Result:**
The child components in ProductTableRow do not stretch fully to align under the ProductTableHeader columns.

**Attempted Solutions:**

Ensured matching flex values across corresponding header and row components.
Applied flex: 1 to the Pressable in ProductTableRow.
Checked for any conflicting styles that might affect alignment.
When i tried by setting the width: 730 the layout become what i expected, but i don't want to set value for width, instead i want to take the remaining screen size.
Question:
How can I ensure that each child component within a ProductTableRow aligns perfectly under its corresponding column in ProductTableHeader?

I've attached a screenshot to illustrate the alignment issue
[image]